# How do I seed specific values in a database every time the app runs?

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have an app that uses SSN's to look up people in a database. I am trying to force the 10 "ssn's" that I use for testing purposes to seed every time I run the app. I am currently dropping the table and reseeding the data with my false data but we are importing data from a real database to ours and I no longer want to do this.

Can someone lead me to a site or give me a hint on how I could go about this?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework at all? Because I believe you can do that in EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Entity Framework you can customize a database initializer that won't drop the database (see near the end of [this page](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm)). You could then put in the false data in the Initialize Database method so that it will run every time.

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged this with Asp.net MVC3?

If this is a web-app, I'd consider using an Application_start event within Global.aspx

Comment: Yes it is a web-app, but I was looking for something that I could add to my data seeder that would allow me to check for changes. Thanks anyway.

Comment: OH I get you now. I misunderstood your intention.